# Theoretically Contract Standard SObject cannot be imported through the API

Tags: api, import, data-import, contracts, status

The Contract Standard SObject has a field named StatusCode that according to the API is nillable and not createable*, hence, theoretically it would not be possible to import records of this SObject.
*It's also not defaultedOnCreate and not nameField.

However if I decide to ignore these rules and try to import a Contract ignoring the SatusCode it gets correctly imported.

I have reviewed all the field properties to see if they was anything that could indicate me that it can be ignored for creation, something like the nameField, however I don't seem to find anything.

Am I missing something? Or would I need to implement an exception to skip this particular field?

If I'm not missing aything it would be nice for Salesforce to add a new property to the fields so that this can be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`Contract.StatusCode` is always derived from `Contract.Status`

```
Type: picklist
Properties: Filter, Group, Restricted picklist, Sort
Description: The status category for the contract. 
             A contract can be Draft, InApproval, or Activated. 
             Label is Status Category.
```

> Status:   Stage that the contract has reached in the contract business process. Your admin can add values to this picklist within three system-defined contract status categories: Draft, In Approval Process, and Activated. You can use these status categories to track contracts within your business process using reports and views.

The Status Category controls some OOTB logic/constraints for Contracts. Only three are available but you can map any number of Status picklist values to the Status Categories in Setup. [Doc ref](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.contract_fields.htm&type=5).

You should always exclude this field in import. If a field is not createable - you should exclude it from import; if it is not updateable, you should exclude it from update/upsert. `StatusCode` is neither.

There are other Sobjects that work this way, notably `Order`

Comment: Hey! Interesting point here, as you just stated, whenever a field is not createable I exclude it from the import, however what's interesting here, is that it is also not nillable, hence its required, and this is the inconsistency I refer to

Comment: autonumber and system audit fields are also `nillable=false` and `createable=false`, though are `defaultedOnCreate=true` so there's something to be said for your assertion of inconsistency with respect to `StatusCode` - but as I said above, use `createable` as a filter to avoid including the field in an insert

Comment: For this particular reason is that I mention also the defaultOnCreate and the nameField properties, you cannot use alone the createable property

Comment: good point - but the assertion in your OP title is not true; you can import `Contract` via API

Comment: Yeep, I tried to summarize the problem in the title saying that **theoretically** it cannot but imported, taking into account the response from the API, but in **practice** it definitely can, as you say